# Is traffic analysis easier for relay adversaries than for network adversaries?

Tags: relays, traffic-analysis, relay-adversary, network-adversary

I gather that relay adversaries employ traffic analysis to determine that two of their relays are part of the same circuit. And I vaguely recall a comment, perhaps on the Tor Project blog, that matching circuit-level traffic is easier than matching packet-level traffic, as network adversaries must do. The argument, as I recall, involved constant cell size for circuit-level traffic vs loss and retransmission complexity for packet-level traffic.

I'm looking for a link for the comment, and also for further explanation and/or resources on the issue.